# vim/emacs plugin to view recursive grep search search results?

Tags: vim, grep, emacs, search

Suppose I have a file formatted like this:

```
file1:123
file2:4444
some/other/file:2233
```

This represents the search results from a command `grep` (i.e. the format `file:line-number`).

I'd like to have a vim plugin which would allow me quickly browse through those hits. It would display a two-pane window (split horizontally) with the top pane showing the hits and the bottom pane showing currently selected hit. Changing the selection in the top pane displays the specified file at the indicated line number in the bottom pane.

Anyone run across something like this? I'd even consider a non-vim solution (emacs/dedicated program, ...).

Answer (score 5):

In Emacs, run open the grep results and run `M-x grep-mode`.

If you saved the grep results in a file that isn't in the directory you ran grep in, you'll need to run `M-x cd` to change to the proper directory.

The `grep` output needs to contain a `:` after the line number, i.e. you need to have `file_name:line_number:text`, where the `text` is optional but the second `:` isn't. You could change this by tuning `grep-regexp-alist`.

Of course, if you run `M-x grep`, all of that works automatically.

Answer (score 3):

In **vim** command mode:

For internal grep,

```
:vimgrep pattern-to-search files
:copen
```

see `:help vimgrep` for help.

For external grep,

```
:grep pattern-to-search files
:copen
```

see `:help grep` for help.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs support this through the *rgrep* and *lgrep* commands (type `M-x rgrep` or `M-x lgrep`, where `M-x` is Emacs' notation for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>), which are included in Emacs at least since version 22.
The command *rgrep* runs a recursive grep search, whereas *lgrep* is limited
to files in a single directory.

They display *grep* results in a separate pane, one per line; you can navigate results by:

- either clicking on a result line (will open the relevant file in another window), or
- repeatedly pressing *C-x `* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed
  by the back-tick key): each time you hit this key combination, the
  current pane will display the next *grep* hit on the
  list.*emphasized text*

More information in the [GNU Emacs manual, chapter "Grep searching"](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Grep-Searching.html)

*Note:* In Emacs' terminology, a pane is called a *window*, and a window is called a *frame*.